# WMD Markdown showing in preview div

Tags: c#, asp.net, wmd

I have just implemented WMD for my editor in an ASP.NET app. The problem is the preview doesn't show the formatted HTML but the markdown instead. So if I use the (surrounded by double stars markdown syntax) I get exactly that in the preview, when I was expecting to get the html version of it.

If I explicitly enter the html tags in the textarea the preview is fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the configuration section (location depends on the WMD version you use) there is a 
**output** attribute, which is probably set to **markdown** or something similar.
Change it to

`output:"HTML"`